# Increase every varchar field length by factor of 5

Tags: mysql, sql, schema

I failed to account for something in my data, and I would like to MySQL increase every varchar field length in one table by factor of 5.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: you mean through automation? based on what it should do that?

Comment: Some symbols in my data are being translated to a 5 character code.  So I want to make room by changing the table field lengths once.  Without typing in each change manually.

Answer (score 0):

"Easy" depend on how many tables and columns you have to modify, but you could select the relevant table_name, column_name, and character_maximum_length values from information_schema.columns into a new table, multiply the length values by 5, and concatenate the values into ALTER TABLE statements.  Then you will need to execute that set of generated statements.

If there are primary and foreign keys using these columns, you will have to drop them first and recreate them afterward.

Comment: He said "factor of 5" but he meant add 5 characters - so varchar(5) becomes varchar(10), not varchar(25)

Comment: Meant factor of 5.  Each character can be 4 chars longer than I originally planned.

Comment: I read that the info in information_schema wasn't always accurate.  Do you know if that is true?

Comment: I have never heard that it is inaccurate.  But you could check it.